# Starting guess for a Boundary Value Problem in a Non-linear Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have read around the Internet and tried to find answers but inevitably, people just chalk the problem up to an application of Newton-Gauss method and then call it a day. My problem is finding a good starting guess (I think.)

$$ u'' - x^2 u(u - 1) = 0 $$

$$ u(1) = 2; u(3) = 4 $$

Solve for x where $ a = 1 \leq x \leq 3 = b $ with $ N + 1 $ equal subintervals.

We start by doing the usual substitution for the second derivative as the central differentiation approximation and multiplying by $ h^2 $:

$$ (u_{j-1} - 2 u_j + u_{j+1}) - h^2 x_j^2 u_j (u_j - 1) = 0 $$

Where $ u_j \approx u(a + jh), j = 1 .. n, n = N - 1 $.

Collect the terms with a factor $ u_j $ in a function $ G(u_j) $ like so:

$$ \begin{align*} G(u_j) &= - 2 u_j - h^2 x_j^2 u_j (u_j - 1) \\ &= u_j (h^2 x_j^2 u_j (1 - u_j) - 2) \\ u_{j-1} + G(u_j) + u_{j+1} &= 0  \end{align*} $$

For our boundaries we have

$$ \begin{align*} j = 1 &\implies 2 + G(u_1) + u_2 = 0 \\  j = n &\implies u_{n-1} + G(u_n) + 4 = 0 \end{align*} $$

---

At this point, what people tell you to do is to use Newton-Gauss to find the roots of the function

$$ F(u_1, ..., u_n) = \begin{matrix} [u_0 + G(u_1) + u_2, \\ ..., \\ u_{n - 1} + G(u_n) + u_{n+1}] \end{matrix} $$

My question is simple: how do you make a good starting guess? Some literature mentions taking the linear case, but I fail to find one in this instance. Am I missing something? I tried making the guess with zeros but it wouldn't converge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had made a mistake in my algebra and hence derivatives, so therefore no convergence. Fixed that and now it works with pretty much any initial guess, even zeros!

Answer (score 2):

My first try would be to take as initial guess
$$
u^0_j=u^0(a+h\,j)\quad\text{with}\quad u^0(x)=x+1.
$$
That is, $u^0$ interpolates linearly the boundary conditions.

Comment: It turns out I had made a mistake in my algebra and hence derivatives, so therefore no convergence. Fixed that and now it works with pretty much any initial guess, even zeros!